# How to narrow down the union type of a class generic?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

This class holds either a single `Item` or an array of items `Item[]`, determined by a setting at runtime (`this.config.isMultiple`).

How can I narrow down the class' generic type with a type guard to `Item[]` in the whole `if (this.isMultiple)`-Block? (which has many, many more accesses than this example, each needing to have an individual typecast, otherwise).

*Minimum working example:*

```js
interface Item { /* ... */ }

class Demo <DATATYPE extends Item | Item[]> {
  config: { isMultiple: boolean; }
  value: DATATYPE;

  get isMultiple(): boolean {
    return this.config.isMultiple;
  }

  addValue(value: Item) {
    if (this.isMultiple) {
      if (!Array.isArray(this.value)) {
        this.value = [] as Item[];
        // TS2322: Type 'Item[]' is not assignable to type 'DATATYPE'. 'Item[]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'DATATYPE', but 'DATATYPE' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Item | Item[]'.
      }
      this.value.push(value);
      // TS2339: Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Item | Item[]'. Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Item'.
    } else {
      this.value = value;
      // TS2322: Type 'Item' is not assignable to type 'DATATYPE'. 'Item' is assignable to the constraint of type 'DATATYPE', but 'DATATYPE' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Item | Item[]'.
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Union This

Provide `this` type to the addValue function in the class.

```
interface MultipleDemoThis<T> {
     config: { isMultiple: true; }
     value: T[];
     get isMultiple(): true;
}

interface SingleDemoThis<T> {
    config: { isMultiple: false; }
    value: T;
    get isMultiple(): false;
}

type DemoThis<T> = MultipleDemoThis<T> | SingleDemoThis<T>

interface Item { /* ... */ }

class Demo<T extends Item> {
  config = { isMultiple: true }
  get isMultiple(): boolean {
    return this.config.isMultiple;
  }

  addValue(this: DemoThis<T>, value: T) {
    if (this.isMultiple) {
      if (!Array.isArray(this.value)) {
        this.value = [];
      }
      this.value.push(value);
    } else {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

## Narrowing using multi-variables

```
class Demo <DATATYPE extends Item> {
  config: { isMultiple: boolean }
  value?: DATATYPE
  values?: DATATYPE[]
  
  get isMultiple(): boolean {
    return this.config.isMultiple
  }

  // Please use a getter or a function to access the data.
  //   this is an example
  getValue() {
    if(this.isMultiple) {
      return this.values
    }
    return this.value
  }

  addValue(value: DATATYPE) {
    if (this.isMultiple) {
      if (!Array.isArray(this.values)) {
        this.values = []
      }
      this.values.push(value)
    } else {
      this.value = value
    }
  }
}
```

You may need to clean `this.values` after switching `isMultiple`.

## Narrowing / Forcing using `as` keyword

```
class Demo <DATATYPE extends Item | Item[]> {
  config: { isMultiple: boolean; }
  value: DATATYPE;

  get isMultiple(): boolean {
    return this.config.isMultiple;
  }

  addValue(value: Item) {
    if (this.isMultiple) {
      if (!Array.isArray(this.value)) {
        this.value = <Item>[] as DATATYPE
      }
      // we can be sure it is an array, so we use `as` to tell TS it must be an Array.
      (this.value as Item[]).push(value)
    } else {
      this.value = value as DATATYPE
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid this does not help:
First, this determines the type from an initial value, that doesn't exist in our case. We need to get that type from the config, even without having a value.
Second, there is never a value pushed to the list in the case of isMultiple.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the answer. For both of the point is about the line `(this.value as Item[]).push(value)`. It will force TS to know that it is an array. I wish it can help.

Comment: That way it works, thank you. I already have a similar workaround in place. As there are many, many more places to fix this (this was just a minimum working example), I wonder how I could do this only once for a whole block, just like I could do with a type guard for simple variable. Maybe I'll have to clarify my question a little...

Comment: IC, you are trying to transpile your code. This question is interesting. I have seen many js code like that. I followed the TS Handbook and found that might need it change the Item struct which may affect other part of your system. Or introduce another function, which does not help much with the `extends` keyword. This two is the easiest way I currently know. This one just submitted might be better.